# Why morphism from initial object to any other given object is unique?

Tags: category-theory

I am following `Bartosz Milewski`'s category theory for programmers.

I understand the argument that the morphism from `void -> any` exists in the sense that its can't be proved otherwise. But can't the same argument be used to show that there are infinitely many of `void -> ()`? How is it unique?

Comment: Isn't that the definition of initial object?

Comment: @ChrisCuster That's the part I am struggling with. Consider two morphism `void -> Bool` `f1` and `f2`. How do you prove that they are identical?

Comment: What is your definition of two morphisms being equal?

Comment: @ZhenLin I am feeling dumb now. The cartesian product of void x Bool is ∅. So only one relation is possible. And the only relation is also a morphism as the first set is empty! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, then an object $C$ is called initial if for all objects $D$, the set (class) $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C,D)$ contains exactly one morphism. Hence, your claim is true by definition of initial object.

Note that if $C$ and $D$ are initial objects, then $C \cong D$ since there are unique morphisms $C \to D$ and $D \to C$. The compositions $C \to C$ and $D \to D$ must necessarily be identities by uniqueness of such morphisms, so the morphisms $C \to D$ and $D \to C$ are inverse to each other.

Comment: What prevents me from saying there are infinitely many morphism from ∅ to N?

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @silentboy What is $\emptyset$? If it is the emptyset, then there is a unique function $\emptyset \to N$, so for instance $\emptyset$ is initial in the category of all sets. Hence, the category of sets has a unique initial object.